# What do empty braces mean in Python?

Tags: python, braces

Please have a look at this snippet:

```
import xlrd,spss
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb=open_workbook('C:/temp/testbook.xls')
sheetnames=[]
for s in wb.sheets():
   sheetnames.append(s.name)
```

Why should I write "`wb.sheets()`" instead of "`wb.sheets`"? And why is it "`s.name`" instead of "`s.name()`"?

I often use empty braces when I'm not supposed to and the other way around. Could anybody tell me what they mean and when I should (not) use them?

Comment: You really want to start with the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). This is very basic Python syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `()` are necessary when the attribute (sheets) is a function you with to call.  The `()` should not be used when the attribute is a value want to use directly rather than make a call on.